# Doubt on a Trigonometry proof

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

In Simmmon's Calculus with Analytic Geometry 3rd edition, on page 299, the following proof for the law of cosines is provided:

> $$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta$$ The proof is routine if we place the
>   triangle in the $xy$-plane as shown in the figure and apply the distance
>   formula to the vertices $(a \cos \theta, a \sin \theta)$ and $(b, 0)$[image].

My doubt is: why are the coordinates of the left vertex $(a \cos \theta, a \sin \theta)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should be the coordinates of the left vertex then?

Comment: Have you ever heard of the term unit circle? If so draw a unit circle assuming $a = 1$. Then draw lines from the point on the left vertex to the $x$-axis and $y$-axis. Hope you can figure out the rest by standard trigonometry.

Comment: The results used there are: $\sin (\pi - \theta) = \sin \theta$ and $\cos(\pi - \theta) = -\cos (\theta)$.

Comment: I think OP wants to know why did $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ make an appearance.

Comment: In that case, OP please take a look at the concept of polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a right-angled triangle to explain this. For a point in the
second quadrant, as you have drawn it here, drop a perpendicular from
your point $P$ to the $x$-axis, meeting it at $Q$. Then $OPQ$ is right-angled with $\angle POQ=\pi-\theta$. Therefore $|PQ|=a\sin(\pi-\theta)$
and $|OQ|=a\cos(\pi-\theta)$. Then $P$ has coordinates
$$(-a\cos(\pi-\theta),a\sin(\pi-\theta))=(a\cos\theta,a\sin\theta).$$
Similar arguments work in each of the other three quadrants.

Answer (score 2):

Because that vertex is what we get applying a rotation of angle $\theta$ to the point $(a,0)$. And applying such a rotation to a point $(x,y)$ gives us $\bigl(x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta),x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are more comfortable with acute angles you may consider the angle $(\pi-\theta).$

Answer (score 0):

This is just the usual notation of parametric coordinates of a point which at a times proves to be very useful. For more information you can refer to the below link

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation

Hope it helps.